# See if a number is equal to 1 or every 5th number

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a number is equal to 1 or every 5th number after that.
Eg. 1,6,11,16,21,... Then I want to set a value.
Something like

```
if (checkForOneOrFifth(rowNumber)){
$("#x"+rowNumber+"_Location").val('myText');
$("#x"+rowNumber+1+"_Location").val('myText');
$("#x"+rowNumber+2+"_Location").val('myText');
$("#x"+rowNumber+3+"_Location").val('myText');
$("#x"+rowNumber+4+"_Location").val('myText');
}
var checkForOneOrFifth = function(number) {
if(something here){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
};
```

Thanks for any help
Scott

Comment: `$("#x" + (rowNumber + 1) + "_Location").val('myText');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `mod` operator to check that for you:

```
var checkforoneorffith = function(number){
  return (number - 1) % 5 == 0;
}
```